# nginx close upstream connection after request

Tags: http, nginx

I need to keep alive my connection between nginx and upstream nodejs.

Just compiled and installed nginx 1.2.0

my configuration file:

```
upstream backend {
    ip_hash;
    server dev:3001;
    server dev:3002;
    server dev:3003;
    server dev:3004;
    keepalive 128;
}

server {
    listen      9000;
    server_name dev;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://backend;
        error_page  404 = 404.png;
    }
}
```

My programe (dev:3001 - 3004) detect that the connection was closed by nginx after response.

[document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#keepalive)

Answer (score 72, accepted):

The [documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#keepalive) states that for http keepalive, you should also set `proxy_http_version 1.1;` and `proxy_set_header Connection "";`

Comment: Would you like to give some more clarification about this config?