# Nginx proxy_pass_header

Tags: node.js, nginx

I'm trying to `proxy_pass_header Connection;` to my node.js server.
But my response header getting overwritten `Connection : keep-alive` Even when I explicitly changed the `Connection : close`.

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you have nginx in front and that will respond based on its own settings. You should use below directive in your nginx conf if you don't want to keep connection alive

```
keepalive_timeout 0;
```

Comment: It solves the problem but right now I'm facing another. keepalive_timeout 0; dosen't let node response header to be Connection: keep-alive. It's always close.

Comment: See if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10395807/nginx-close-upstream-connection-after-request

Comment: What I really want is to control the Connection from node.js based on some logic. Is it possible?

Comment: Try this `add_header Connection $upstream_http_connection;`. This will try and response with your upstream connection response header

Comment: Also see if this is needed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10395807/nginx-close-upstream-connection-after-request