# Nginx error - 2017/08/17 06:06:43 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while connecting to upstream

Tags: nginx

I am getting a lot of errors in the Nginx logs like the below lines.

```
2017/08/17 06:06:43 [error] 6233#6233: *1999792 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.4.24, server: cmdc
```

I actually followed this StackOverflow link [nginx close upstream connection after request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10395807/nginx-close-upstream-connection-after-request) and added the below parameters in the Nginx config.

```
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_set_header Connection "";
```

But still, i am getting a lot of errors. Can someone please help me here?

Comment: Check the upstream server is not out of connections, Nginx is complaining that it can't contact that server, it's not a Nginx issue.

Comment: @Geoffrey.. It's able to connect to the server. This issue happens only for few seconds and then it goes. To add, there were few Warnings before the error. After that Nginx connects to the server and forwards the request.

Comment: What is the back end server? Is it running some script? Is the script finishing? Is the back end server running out of connections? This would explain your problem.