# Nginx throws intermittent Connection refused error

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

Nginx throws connection refused error intermittently. Here is the error stack trace,

> [error] 12035#12035: *177490 connect() failed (111: Connection
>   refused) while connecting to upstream, client: xxx.xx.xx, server:
>   xxx.xx.xx, request: "POST / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "xxxx", host:
>   "xxx.xx.xxx"

These errors won't occur all the time, but they appear in the log file intermittently. I think it's a serious issue since these errors occure very often. Can someone please shed some light on this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [nginx close upstream connection after request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10395807/nginx-close-upstream-connection-after-request)