# Gateway timeout with Spring cloud gateway and Nginx as reverse proxy

Tags: java, nginx, spring-cloud, nginx-reverse-proxy, spring-cloud-gateway

I created an API gateway for my application and it will act as a front controller for other microservices.
In my production setup I use Nginx as a reverse proxy for my gateway

The API gateway is running on port 8080

Nginx configured as below:

gateway-api.conf:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name api.example.com;
    location / {
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Connection "";
        proxy_pass http://localhost:30010/;
        keepalive_timeout 500s;
    }
    keepalive_timeout 500s;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/api.log;  
    error_log /var/log/nginx/api_error.log;
}
```

Timeout setting in nginx.conf:

```
proxy_connect_timeout 300;
proxy_send_timeout 300;
proxy_read_timeout 300;
send_timeout 300;
```

Spring cloud gateway gradle file:

```
compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-gateway')
 compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-openfeign')
 compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
 compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security')

springBootVersion=2.0.3.RELEASE
springDMPVersion=1.0.4.RELEASE
springPlatformBomVersion=Cairo-SR2
springCloudVersion=Finchley.RELEASE
```

Gateway application:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.example"})
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.example"})
@EnableFeignClients(basePackages = "com.example")
public class GatewayApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(GatewayApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Problem statement:

In one of my microservices, one REST API takes more than 3 minutes to complete.
If I call this API via `nginx(api.example.com)`, it fails **exactly after 1 minute** and gives HTTP status 504.

curl:

```
curl --request GET \
  --url http://api.example.com/hellomicroservice/api/take/moretime
```

error:

```
504 Timeout while reading the response from Server
```

There are no error logs in nginx or the API gateway.

Access log from nginx:

```
203.129.213.102 - - [01/Apr/2019:08:14:33 +0000] "GET hellomicroservice/api/take/moretime HTTP/1.1" 499 0 "-" "PostmanRuntime/7.3.0"
```

But when I make a call of the same API directly to the gateway (on gateway port 8080), the request is processed successfully.

curl with gateway port:

```
curl --request GET \
  --url http://api.example.com:8080/hellomicroservice/api/take/moretime
```

---

**Edit:**

If I apply the Nginx timeout settings as less than 60 Seconds (e.g. 30 seconds), the request gets timed out in a specified time interval. But if I set the Nginx timeout to be more than 60 seconds, let's 300 Seconds, the request gets timed out after 60 seconds.

Comment: what error log on API gateway and nginx error log when you `curl` via reverse proxy ?

Comment: No error logs in nginx and gateway, added access logs

Comment: can you try adding  proxy_read_timeout 300s; in server block server {
  proxy_read_timeout 300s;

Comment: @RadhaMohanMaheshwari Tried, not working

Comment: can you try replace localhost:8080 in nginx setting with api.example.com:8080 ?

Comment: In a production deployment, we are using AWS EKS and we are not fetching this issue on production with same config files

Answer (score 1):

It seems the request time-outs are not the problem for you. Its the connection timeout. 
I think we need to look on the header of

> Connection

AFAIK, the `Connection` header defines, the connection should be persistent or who has the authority to maintain/close it. If the connection was `keep-alive` , then the connection will be persistent. For the keep-alive connections, the client occasionaly sends a TCP ping to ensure the server is still alive and holding the connection. As per the **[curl](https://ec.haxx.se/usingcurl-timeouts.html)** this time by default is every 60 seconds.

Now the `nginx` has to be configured to accept connections and keep it alive for a while using the **`keepalive_timeout`** directive. If this is not there, then `nginx` will not [keep the connections alive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#keepalive_timeout).

This should be the reason why nginx says **499**  in the logs. **HTTP499** is a cutom error in nginx which says the client closed the connection. In your case the `curl` closed it. Why `curl`closed it? because nginx did not respond to the TCP ping of 60 seconds as the keep-alive is not enabled.

Adding the **`keepalive_timeout`** to ~500 or a higher value than the application timeout should solve your problem.

Now, why it worked with tomcat directly? I think spring enables the alive timeout to be infinite or a very higher value. Normally in tomcat also its 60 seconds.

I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Setting `keepalive_timeout 500;` did not work, same error
When I checked the response header I found the connection header as `Connection →close`

Comment: Set like keepalive_timeout 500s; Keep it in the server section or the location. I think the unit 's' must be there.

Comment: tried after putting in server and location section with `keepalive_timeout 500s;` but same error

Comment: May be you should try with `--no-keepalive` option in curl. I assume Nginx is  not respecting the keep-alive connection. You can also check the same with some other clients like http-client / Fiddler or any for that matter. Use of keep-alive is good only if you do multiple operations with same connection.

Comment: `Connection` just tells the origin server what to do with the TCP socket once the response is finished, the idea being that the client will send further requests along the stream. In this case that would be between curl/postman and nginx. I think it's more likely that nginx is just getting bored and killing the request, which is odd as the `read_timeout` is 5 mins..

Answer (score 0):

Keepalive may still not be enabled for the upstream due to your configuration missing the proxy_http_version key.

Quote from: https://www.nginx.com/blog/tuning-nginx/#proxy_http_version

> To enable keepalive connections to upstream servers you must also include the following directives in the configuration:

```
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_set_header Connection "";
```

I'd also keep the keepalive_timeout in the config as Kris had suggested.

Comment: You might have a formatting problem. The example configs show that the "server" block is typically wrapped in an "http { }" block, and the "keepalive_timeout" key is typically a child of the http block, and not the server or location block. You might check your other keys to make sure that they are all under the correct parent too. 

Also, do you have multiple nginx configs active in the configuration directory?

Answer (score 0):

Try to put your timeout settings in /etc/nginx/conf.d/timeout.conf (if it is not there create one). Set below settings ,

```
proxy_connect_timeout 600;
proxy_send_timeout 600;
proxy_read_timeout 600;
send_timeout 600;
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is one of the problems that can happen because of many other things. This is a solution that worked for me (I was also getting errors in `/var/log/nginx/error.log`:

> 2020/12/30 21:47:47 [error] 26765#26765: *13064 upstream timed out
> (110: Connection timed out) while connecting to upstream, client: XXX,
> server: example.com, request: "GET /eshop HTTP/1.0", upstream:
> "http://[::1]:8080/error_50x.html", host: "example.com"

Strangely enough, this was not happening on my laptop, but only on my server. So I checked the IPs and it turns out it's maybe because of missing ::1 address. When I added it to the *lo* network device, I couldn't replicate the timeouts.

```
sudo ip a add ::1/128 dev lo
```

Next: (this is my understanding, I am not 100 % sure about it:) Also, since the overhead for keeping a connection to a localhost Java service seems to be higher than just dropping that connection and connecting again when another request is made, it's recommended to use the following settings for proxies (in your nginx's site .conf):

```
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_set_header Connection "";
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/10396874/3223505